# How to draw a mattress in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make a nice picture of the top view of a mattress in TikZ. I have made two attempts, one with wavy lines and one with a grid pattern:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

With wavy lines:

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3cm,y=0.3cm]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\br{16}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ht{20}

    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

    \pgfmathsetmacro\nrcurve{6}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nrrow{12}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\brcurve{\br/\nrcurve}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\brcurvepart{\br/\nrcurve/4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rowht{\ht/\nrrow}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\curveampl{\rowht/5}

    \newcommand\curvepart[2]{
        (#1,#2+\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2-\curveampl)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2-\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*4,#2+\curveampl)
        }
    \newcommand\curvepartneg[2]{
        (#1,#2-\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2+\curveampl)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2+\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*4,#2-\curveampl)
        }

    \draw[line width=1pt]
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\nrcurve} {
        \foreach \y in {2,4,...,\nrrow} {
            \curvepart{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y - \rowht/2 - \rowht}
            \curvepartneg{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y-\rowht/2} } };

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,\ht);
    \coordinate (C) at (\br,\ht);
    \coordinate (D) at (\br,0);

    \draw[rounded corners=2mm,line width=1pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

With grid pattern:

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3cm,y=0.3cm]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\br{16}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ht{20}

    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

    \pgfmathsetmacro\nrlines{12}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\linediff{\ht/12+\br/12}

    \draw[line width=1pt]
        \foreach \x in {2,...,\nrlines} {
            (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,0) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht)
            (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,0)
        };

    \fill[white]    (0,-1) rectangle (-\ht,\ht+1)
            (\br,-1) rectangle (\br+\ht,\ht+1);

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,\ht);
    \coordinate (C) at (\br,\ht);
    \coordinate (D) at (\br,0);

    \draw[rounded corners=2mm,line width=1pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the following result:

[image: Two TikZ mattresses]

While these aren't terrible, in my opinion, they could certainly be improved. For example, they currently feel very flat (and not so soft), making the second look like a waffle.

> How could I make these look more like the top view of a real life mattress?

---

Some context: I would like to use the mattress to explain symmetry groups, inspired by [Group Theory in the Bedroom](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/group-theory-in-the-bedroom)

Comment: At first I thought "mattress" was a typo for "matrix" :) (+1, btw)!

Comment: You could use shading near the seams.  This could be done using radial shading for each individual square.  You might achieve a poor man's shading by shifting the grid and using opacity.

Comment: "*more like the top view of a real life mattress?*" The question is  how a real life mattress would like look?! What is the final output you're looking for?

Comment: @Croco: I have no specific image in mind that I want to aim for, I simply hope to achieve a picture where people who look at it say "it's a mattress!", and not "that ice-cream cone has a weird shape", as could be possible with the grid.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sort of OK...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[looseness=0.5]
\shade [left color=gray!20, right color=gray!10, shading angle=45,
  rounded corners=0.25cm] (-.125,-.125) rectangle (6.125,8.125);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5} \foreach \y in {0,...,7}
  \shade [left color=gray!20, right color=white, shading angle=45, shift={(\x,\y)}] 
    (0,0) 
    to [bend left] (0,1/2) to [bend right] (0,1) 
    to [bend left] (1,1) 
    to [bend left] (1,0.5) to [bend right] (1,0)
    to [bend right] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My favourite, although I would prefer inverted colours of the seams and of the cases. This would give the seams a more sunken-in appearance.

Comment: Looks comfortable!

Comment: Ah, this is the type of things for which I just do not have enough experience. I like it a lot, this is the mattress I ended up using, albeit with the suggestions by AlexG. I have the first shading going from left `black!10` to right `black!15`, and the small shadings from left `white` to right `black!20`. Finally, I used 10 by 8 smaller shadings. Now, so fluffy, must resist taking a nap...

Answer (score 13):

Just for fun, another solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

With wavy lines:

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3cm,y=0.3cm]
  \pgfmathsetmacro\br{16}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ht{20}

  \path[rounded corners=2mm,use as bounding box,clip] (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

  \fill[gray!30](0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

  \pgfmathsetmacro\nrcurve{6}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\nrrow{12}

  \pgfmathsetmacro\brcurve{\br/\nrcurve}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\brcurvepart{\br/\nrcurve/4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\rowht{\ht/\nrrow}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\curveampl{\rowht/5}

  \newcommand\curvepart[2]{
    (#1,#2+\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart,#2)
    (#1+\brcurvepart,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2-\curveampl)
    (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2-\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2)
    (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*4,#2+\curveampl)
  }
  \newcommand\curvepartneg[2]{
    (#1,#2-\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart,#2)
    (#1+\brcurvepart,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2+\curveampl)
    (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2+\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2)
    (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*4,#2-\curveampl)
  }

  \draw[line width=1pt,black!75]
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\nrcurve} {
    \foreach \y in {2,4,...,\nrrow} {
      \curvepart{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y - \rowht/2 - \rowht}
      \curvepartneg{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y-\rowht/2}
    }
  };

  \begin{scope}[yshift=1pt]
    \draw[line width=1pt,gray!60]
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\nrcurve} {
      \foreach \y in {2,4,...,\nrrow} {
        \curvepart{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y - \rowht/2 - \rowht}
        \curvepartneg{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y-\rowht/2}
      }
    };
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-1pt]
    \draw[line width=1pt,gray!15]
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\nrcurve} {
      \foreach \y in {2,4,...,\nrrow} {
        \curvepart{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y - \rowht/2 - \rowht}
        \curvepartneg{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y-\rowht/2}
      }
    };
  \end{scope}

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,\ht);
  \coordinate (C) at (\br,\ht);
  \coordinate (D) at (\br,0);

  \draw[rounded corners=2mm,line width=1pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

With grid pattern:

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3cm,y=0.3cm]
  \pgfmathsetmacro\br{16}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\ht{20}

  \path[rounded corners=2mm,use as bounding box,clip] (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

  \fill[gray!30](0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

  \pgfmathsetmacro\nrlines{12}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\linediff{\ht/12+\br/12}

  \draw[line width=1pt,black!75]
  \foreach \x in {2,...,\nrlines} {
    (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,0) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht)
    (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,0)
  };

  \begin{scope}[yshift=1pt]
  \draw[line width=1pt,gray!60]
  \foreach \x in {2,...,\nrlines} {
    (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,0) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht)
    (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,0)
  };
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-1pt]
  \draw[line width=1pt,gray!15]
  \foreach \x in {2,...,\nrlines} {
    (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,0) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht)
    (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,0)
  };
  \end{scope}

  \fill[white]    (0,-1) rectangle (-\ht,\ht+1)
  (\br,-1) rectangle (\br+\ht,\ht+1);

  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,\ht);
  \coordinate (C) at (\br,\ht);
  \coordinate (D) at (\br,0);

  \draw[rounded corners=2mm,line width=1pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The first looks good to me, but the second looks more like beveled glass.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3cm,y=0.3cm]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\br{16}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ht{20}

    %\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

    \pgfmathsetmacro\nrcurve{6}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nrrow{12}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\brcurve{\br/\nrcurve}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\brcurvepart{\br/\nrcurve/4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rowht{\ht/\nrrow}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\curveampl{\rowht/5}

    \newcommand\curvepart[2]{
        (#1,#2+\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2-\curveampl)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2-\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*4,#2+\curveampl)
        }
    \newcommand\curvepartneg[2]{
        (#1,#2-\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2+\curveampl)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*2,#2+\curveampl) cos (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2)
        (#1+\brcurvepart*3,#2) sin (#1+\brcurvepart*4,#2-\curveampl)
        }

    \draw[line width=5pt,color=lightgray]
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\nrcurve} {
        \foreach \y in {2,4,...,\nrrow} {
            \curvepart{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y - \rowht/2 - \rowht}
            \curvepartneg{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y-\rowht/2} } };

    \draw[line width=1pt,color=gray]
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,\nrcurve} {
        \foreach \y in {2,4,...,\nrrow} {
            \curvepart{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y - \rowht/2 - \rowht}
            \curvepartneg{\brcurve*\x-\brcurve}{\rowht*\y-\rowht/2} } };


    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,\ht);
    \coordinate (C) at (\br,\ht);
    \coordinate (D) at (\br,0);

    \draw[rounded corners=2mm,line width=1pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.3cm,y=0.3cm]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\br{16}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ht{20}

    %\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

    \pgfmathsetmacro\nrlines{12}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\linediff{\ht/12+\br/12}

    \begin{scope}
      \clip[rounded corners=2mm] (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

      \draw[rounded corners=2mm,line width=4pt,color=lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (\br,\ht);

      \foreach \x in {2,...,\nrlines} {
        \draw[line width=5pt,color=lightgray]
            (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,0) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht);
        \draw[line width=5pt,color=lightgray]
            (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,0);
        }

      \draw[line width=1pt,color=gray]
        \foreach \x in {2,...,\nrlines} {
            (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,0) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht)
            (-\ht+\x*\linediff-\linediff,\ht) -- (\x*\linediff-\linediff,0)
        };
    \end{scope}

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,\ht);
    \coordinate (C) at (\br,\ht);
    \coordinate (D) at (\br,0);

    \draw[rounded corners=2mm,line width=1pt] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have kind of a weird [love-hate relationship](https://xkcd.com/1726/) with Unicode...

Here is [Unicode Character 'BED' (U+1F6CF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6cf/index.htm).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=20]{Symbola}
\begin{document}
\Uchar"1F6CF
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not related with a mattress but I like to see knew ideas that are possible to be done with LaTeX... ;) +1

Comment: @Henri Menke  Where could be found the Symbola font file ?

Comment: @SDrolet That is actually a very good question, because the [offical website](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) does not have a download link (anymore?).  But the license permits redistribution, so I uploaded the file for you here https://transfer.sh/6AQpo/Symbola_hint.ttf (link valid for 14 days).  There is also a backup from 2018/03/07 on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20180307013123/http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/Symbola.zip